# using "or" for split

Tags: c#, split

```
var list = string.Join(",", item.Split(new string[] { "2|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

I use above code and it works well.

I want to split like below,

**2| or 3| or 4| or 5| or 6| or 7|**

If value is

2|222 program will continue to working.

if value is

5|232 program will continue to working.

i want program working without exception.

How can i use **"or"** according to my scerenio ?

Comment: How this question related to LINQ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You may want to be more explicit about the desired output

Comment: I want to split 2| or 3| or 4| or 5| or 6| or 7| without exception.Value comes with 2 with 3 with 4 , it is not certain.

Comment: just add more `"3|","4|"...` in the `new string[]...` in `Split` method?

Comment: Provide some sample values of `item`, and what you are trying to put in `list`. If item has value `2|222` then your join makes no sense

Comment: I assume you want to split by `d|` where `d` is an arbitary digit. Use regex.

Comment: @KingKing if you want answer , i will accept your answer as correct

Comment: @user2902180 see my answer for the `Regex.Replace`, you may like it because of its conciseness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some `particular set` of format to care about, not all has the format `\d|`, if so you could also try using `Regex`, but for the simplicity enough, we can always use `string.Split` with an array of `string` passed in to split the string by any one of the array elements, something like this:

```
var list = string.Join(",", item.Split(new string[] { "2|", "3|", "4|", "5|", "6|", "7|" }, 
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

For `regex version`, you should use the `Regex.Replace` like this:

```
var list = Regex.Replace(item, "(?<![2-7][|])[2-7][|](?![2-7][|])",",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Regex.Split with pattern like this [2-7]+|
replace [2-7] with \d if you need all digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d\|");
var splitted = regex.Split(yourInput);
```

Comment: what does it mean "d" ?

Comment: `\d` is a character class matches and digit check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#character_classes) for more info